# twitter bootstrap version 3.0 rc1 NameError: .make-column is undefined

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, sublimetext2, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap v 3.0 RC1 and I installed node and npm to compile less to css when I save the less file.

I include the bootstrap.css file into my html head, when I save the bootstrap.less, it compiles it into css like you would expect.

I created another .less file, (theme.less) within the same bootstrap/less directory where bootstrap.less resides with all the imports, thinking it would include those styles too, but it keeps giving me the following error when I try to compile the theme.less file:

```
NameError: .make-column is undefined in /path/to/assets/bootstrap/less/theme.less

/* ------- Theme styling ------- */
.content-body {
    .make-column(10);
}
```

I assume it is undefined since theme.less does not have a clue the .make-column mixin is, I am new to this so I am trying to figure out how to do this correctly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code works (on linux)

1. create theme.less as above
2. add `@import "theme.less";` **at the end** of bootstrap.less
3. compile by running `grunt dist` in your bootstrap folder or `lessc bootstrap.less` in your less folder

The result, the last lines of bootstrap.css contain:

```
/* ------- Theme styling ------- */

.content-body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .content-body {
    float: left;
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
```

See also: [Twitter's Bootstrap 3.x semantic mobile grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307137/twitters-bootstrap-3-x-semantic-mobile-grid/17308128)