# How can you add a class within a class in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say you have 500 pages that all have the `content` class and you want them to follow the autosizing `col-xs-6` from bootstrap.

You don't want to have to add the `col-xs-6` to all of them individually.  Is there a way to add this class as a class within another class (look below) without having to specify every element (such as height, width, @media etc)?

**CSS:**

```
.content{
    .col-xs-6
    {
     /* load col-xs-6 into .content */
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't have classes. It has class selectors, which select elements by class. Importing one CSS class to another makes no sense.

Comment: there are a number of ways to do this using css frameworks - or, if you're using a build process, css modules can compose for you: https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/

Comment: If you're using a preprocessor like Sass, you can `@extend` one class into another, which will essentially copy all of its properties. Otherwise you can just copy/paste out the styles from `.col-xs-6` to `.content` in your CSS file.

Comment: So you have to use the individual elements from a class.  The css-tricks is handy too.  I will look into Sass too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in order to do extension like you are asking, you cannot use raw CSS. You need to use something like SCSS: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SCSS_FOR_SASS_USERS.html

Unfortunately you cannot extend the Bootstrap grid because it is dynamically generated: [Can Bootstrap 3 Grid Be Extended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341963/can-bootstrap-3-grid-be-extended)